# Error in Kubernetes setup : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have backend of mobile apps built as docker container images. I created two setups, one using docker compose and another using Kubernetes and successfully running all images on both setups. For testing, I have one Python script which will send 1000 REST API requests to backend. The script is working fine on docker compose setup but giving below error in Kuberenetes setup after around 900 successful requests. On docker compose setup script is working fine even for 5000 requests. What could be the issue with Kuberenetes setup? Below is the Python script. I simply switch the server IP in the script to toggle between docker compose and kubernetes.

Error :

```
Exception in thread Thread-1120 (run_hc_call):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 461, in getresponse
    httplib_response = super().getresponse()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\http\client.py", line 1378, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\http\client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\socket.py", line 706, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 470, in increment
    raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\util.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 461, in getresponse
    httplib_response = super().getresponse()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\http\client.py", line 1378, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\http\client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python3115\Lib\socket.py", line 706, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Python Script:

```
import requests as requests
import logging
import threading


thread_count = 1000

logging.basicConfig(
     filename='log_file_name.log',
     level=logging.ERROR,
     format= '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
     datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
     filemode='w'
 )
logger = logging.getLogger()

docker_server = '<public ip>'
kubernetes_server = '<public ip>'
#server = docker_server
server = kubernetes_server

port = "82"
login_ep = "hcweb/account/login"

params = {"ReturnUrl": "/hcweb"}

payload_username = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'}

session = requests.Session()
res = session.get(f"http://{server}:{port}/hcweb", allow_redirects=False)
url = res.headers["Location"]
res2 = session.get(url)
AntiforgeryToken = res2.headers['Set-Cookie'].split(";")[0]

headersAntiforgeryToken = {'Cookie': AntiforgeryToken}


pres = session.post(url, allow_redirects=False, headers=headersAntiforgeryToken, data=payload_username)

HealthCheckToken = pres.headers['Set-Cookie'].split(";")[0]

ping_url = f"http://{server}:{port}/hcweb/home/CheckApi"

paramsIdentity = {'serviceName': 'Identity Api'}
paramsPicking = {'serviceName': 'Picking Api'}
paramsOrganization = {'serviceName': 'Organization Api'}
paramsStocktake = {'serviceName': 'Stocktake Api'}
paramsGoodsin = {'serviceName': 'Goodsin Api'}
paramsTransfer = {'serviceName': 'Transfer Api'}
paramsStoreStockLocation = {'serviceName': 'Store Stock Location Api'}

service_names = ['Identity Api', 'Picking Api', 'Organization Api', 'Stocktake Api', 'Transfer Api', 'Store Stock Location Api']

headersHC = {'Cookie': f"{AntiforgeryToken};{HealthCheckToken}", "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                "Pragma": "no-cache",
             'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}


threads = []
def run_hc_call(service_name):
    res4 = session.get(ping_url, headers=headersHC, params={'serviceName': service_name})
    logger.error(f"{service_name}, {res4.status_code}")

for n in range(0,thread_count):
    sn = service_names[n % len(service_names)]
    t = threading.Thread(target=run_hc_call, args=(sn,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

# Wait all threads to finish.
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

I tried to search the error on internet but could not find any solution.
I expect same script should run successfully on both setups.

Comment: You're using threads to make the HTTP GET requests all at close to exactly the same time.  Are you overloading the remote process in some way, and it's crashing?  If you remove the `threading` parts and make the calls serially, does it run better?

Comment: @davidMaze Thanks for your comments. I did not see any crash or service restarts on both setups. With serial calls it is working fine on Kubernetes setup. Question is if it is working fine with threading on Docker compose setup then why not on Kubernetes setup ? The main purpose of the script is the load testing but it is not working on kubernetes.